# Fastest way to copy a file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

The project that I am working on (Node.js) implies lots of operations with the file system (copying, reading, writing, etc.).

Which methods are the fastest?

Comment: It's a good question, though it is interesting that it gets 25 upvotes when other similar format questions will get 3 or 4 downvotes right away for not meeting the SO "standards" (maybe the javascript tag is crawled by kinder people :)

Comment: Mostly we're just fresh new and excited about this whole "files" business after years of normalizing browsers.

Comment: The only correct answer on the page is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46253698/128511). None of the other answers actually copy files. Files on MacOS and Windows have other metadata that is lost by just copying bytes. Examples of data not copied by any other answer on this page, [windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-streams) and [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228444/how-do-i-create-a-named-fork-and-store-data-in-it). Even on Unix the other answers don't copy the creation date, something that's often important when copying a file.

Answer (score 939, accepted):

Use the standard built-in way [`fs.copyFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback):

```
const fs = require('fs');

// File destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('source.txt', 'destination.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
```

If you have to support old end-of-life versions of Node.js - here is how you do it in versions that do not support `fs.copyFile`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('test.log').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('newLog.log'));
```

Comment: Just remember that in real life, you'd want to check both the `createReadStream` and `createWriteStream` for errors, so you wouldn't get a one-liner (though it would still be just as fast).

Comment: How much faster/slower is this than executing the raw `cp test.log newLog.log` via `require('child_process').exec`?

Comment: Well `copy` is not portable on Window, contrary to a full Node.js solution.

Comment: How about closing the files, does this code keep them opened after copy completed?

Comment: @OlegMihailik Both streams are closed by default. readstream is closed as such by node. writestream can be remained open if you pass `{ end: false}` to pipe, otherwise will be closed by default. See here http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options

Comment: Unfortunately on my system using streams is extremely slow compared to   `child_process.execFile('/bin/cp', ['--no-target-directory', source, target])`.

Comment: I used this method and all I got was a blank file on write. any ideas why? `fs.createReadStream('./init/xxx.json').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('xxx.json'));`

Comment: @Timmerz I had the same issue. The file would be blank and node would just hold a handle to that file forever.  I used the fs-extra module's copy method instead

Comment: your code as written cannot be used together with `process.exit` because the latter terminates all IO without waiting for the streams to finish their data exchange

Comment: This is a common way. But if I want do things after copy, I must listen to an event "end". This is not convenient.

Comment: I make a copy of a file just after having created it, and it gives a blank file as a result. I'm not sure that using streams to copy files is a good practice. Best is to use `fs-extra.copySync` (see other answer in this thread), it works a lot better.

Comment: @Timmerz I had the same problem. I used the solution given below by Tester and it worked.

Comment: Note: "copy a file" implies a complete clone of the file, not just the data within the file. Copying a file would include the creation date of the original. When you're streaming from one file to another, you are copying the data, not the file.

Comment: Mikhail 's answer below uses Node's internal `fs.copyFile` function and is the preferred solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46253698

Comment: this is not "copying a file". Files have things like creation dates (not copied with the code above). Files on MacOS and Windows also have other data streams (not copied with the code above). See the `fs.copyFile` answer. Looking in the node source `fs.copyFile` uses the OS level copy on MacOS and Windows and so should actually copy the files where as the code above mearly creates a new file and copies to bytes to the new file.

Comment: using `copyFile()` is better when you care about privileges, in my case I had to copy an executable to my linux `/tmp/` directory, using the stream solution copy the file with non executable privileges, so the `copyFile()` is the one to go with, It would be great if you mention it in your solution.

Comment: haha @Timmerz you called the file`xxx.json` reminds of a teacher who put the example URL in a demo to xxx.com

Comment: Hi from the project, I edited this answer to reflect the current state of affairs (copyFile existing on every non EoL version of Node.js) - hope that's ok.

Answer (score 298):

Same mechanism, but this adds error handling:

```
function copyFile(source, target, cb) {
  var cbCalled = false;

  var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
  rd.on("error", function(err) {
    done(err);
  });
  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
  wr.on("error", function(err) {
    done(err);
  });
  wr.on("close", function(ex) {
    done();
  });
  rd.pipe(wr);

  function done(err) {
    if (!cbCalled) {
      cb(err);
      cbCalled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that cbCalled flag is needed because pipe errors trigger an error on both streams. Source and destination streams.

Comment: How do you handle the error if the source file doesn't exist? Destination file still gets created in that case.

Comment: I think an error in the `WriteStream` will only unpipe it. You would have to call `rd.destroy()` yourself. At least that's what happened to me. Sadly there's not much documentation except from the source code.

Comment: what does the `cb` stand for? what should we pass in as the third argument?

Comment: @SaiyanGirl 'cb' stands for "callback". You should pass in a function.

Comment: @Robert , @pilau you could always listen to the open event `rd.on('open', function() {})`, and create the write stream there.

Comment: @Marc, that's a very good idea, regarding John Poe's question. I can't really remember well anymore, but I think I was talking about something different. Any error while or after opening the source or target file doesn't close the other stream. You can't really only rely on the `open` event. I think in my case I actually wanted to *move* the file and there was an accidental write error at some point, so `copyFile` dutifully returned the error. My app then tried it again successfully and `unlink`ed the source file. But it still showed up in `readdir` because of the open handle.

Comment: @Mike Schilling, yes, that is fast. But if I try to copy lots of files one after each other within a short time period I get `ERROR: There are some read requests waiting on finished stream`. I guess a stream is unique and instead of waiting for one to finish before starting it just breaks. Any ideas on how to handle this? Thanks

Comment: I understood why. Yes it can’t be twice at one. So basically what I did: I created a recursive function that executes the calls one after each other. There goes your performance :D

Comment: @Robert `.destroy()` is now the official way to close a readable stream as per the documentation - https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error

Answer (score 159):

Since Node.js 8.5.0 we have the new [**fs.copyFile**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback) and [**fs.copyFileSync**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfilesync_src_dest_flags) methods.

Usage example:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// File "destination.txt" will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('source.txt', 'destination.txt', (err) => {
    if (err) 
        throw err;
    console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer on the page. None of the other answers actually copy files. Files on MacOS and Windows have other metadata that is lost by just copying bytes. Examples of data not copied by any other answer on this page, [windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-streams) and [macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228444/how-do-i-create-a-named-fork-and-store-data-in-it). Even on Unix the other answer don't copy the creation date, something that's often important when copying a file.

Comment: well sadly this fails to copy everything on mac. Hopefully they'll fix it: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/30575

Comment: BTW keep in mind that `copyFile()` is bugged while overwriting longer files. Courtesy of `uv_fs_copyfile()` till Node v8.7.0 (libuv 1.15.0). see https://github.com/libuv/libuv/pull/1552

Comment: Does this work if a file is on a server? I want to copy from "http: //www.example.com/file.pdf" to my local node js server, "/pdf"

Comment: This gives me the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "mode" argument must be integer. Received type function`

Answer (score 149):

I was not able to get the `createReadStream/createWriteStream` method working for some reason, but using the [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.org/package/fs-extra) npm module it worked right away. I am not sure of the performance difference though.

`npm install --save fs-extra`

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');

fs.copySync(path.resolve(__dirname, './init/xxx.json'), 'xxx.json');
```

Comment: This is the best option now

Comment: Using syncronous code in node kills your application performance.

Comment: Oh please... The question is about *fastest* method to copy a file. While *fastest* is always subjective, I don't think a synchronous piece of code has any business here.

Comment: Fastest to implement or fastest to execute? Differing priorities mean this is a valid answer.

Comment: fs-extra also has asynchronous methods, i.e. `fs.copy(src, dst, callback);`, and these should resolve @mvillar's concern.

Comment: @Krumia I was - am - under the impression that if there is only 1 task at hand it does not make any difference if I use sync or async code ... just checking my knowledge nothing more, nothing less...

Comment: @Paul There's plenty of use-cases for synchronous code in the NodeJS ecosystem, so I'm not sure I understand @Krumia's reservation. The one place to absolutely avoid synchronous functions is when responsiveness is paramount (such as when writing a server). Even then, you could utilize synchronous code by forking a new VM with `require('child').fork(...)` since it wouldn't block the main event loop. It's all about context and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, I think if you need performance or non blocking for larger files for example you would definitely want to look into the async methods.

Comment: I tried using fs.copySync(path.resolve(__dirname,'./init/xxx.json'), 'xxx.json'); also I tried using copy method , also createReadStream solution discussed earlier in this thread . Still getting the blank file . File does get copied to the desired folder . If i rename it , it will delete the original file but I need to make multiple copies of the same file . Any ideas how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 76):

Fast to write and convenient to use, with promise and error management:

```
function copyFile(source, target) {
  var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    rd.on('error', reject);
    wr.on('error', reject);
    wr.on('finish', resolve);
    rd.pipe(wr);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    rd.destroy();
    wr.end();
    throw error;
  });
}
```

The same with async/await syntax:

```
async function copyFile(source, target) {
  var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
  try {
    return await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      rd.on('error', reject);
      wr.on('error', reject);
      wr.on('finish', resolve);
      rd.pipe(wr);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    rd.destroy();
    wr.end();
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when no more input exists (broken network share), but the write still succeeds? Will both reject (from read) and resolve (from write) be called? What if both read/write fails (bad disk sectors during read, full disk during write)? Then reject will be called twice. A Promise solution based on Mike's answer with a flag (unfortunately) seems to be the only viable solution that properly considers error handling.

Comment: The promise is resolved once the copy succeed. If it's rejected, its state is settled and calling reject multiple times won't make no difference.

Comment: I just tested `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve(1); resolve(2); reject(3); reject(4); console.log("DONE"); }).then(console.log.bind(console), function(e){console.log("E", e);});` and looked up the [spec](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects) on this and you are right: *Attempting to resolve or reject a resolved promise has no effect.* Perhaps you could extend your answer and explain why you have written the function in this way? Thanks :-)

Comment: By the way, `close` should be `finish` for Writable streams.

Comment: And if you wonder why your application never closes after pipe errors on `/dev/stdin`, that is a bug https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/25375

Comment: @Lekensteyn, you are right. 'close' should be 'finish' according to [official API](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish).

Comment: According to API: "One important caveat is that if the Readable stream emits an error during processing, the Writable destination is not closed automatically. If an error occurs, it will be necessary to manually close each stream in order to prevent memory leaks."

Comment: It seems that the "finish" event is unfortunately also send if the stream could not be written because of access restrictions. "finish" doesn't mean "success"

Comment: @devarni wha happens in that case? I mean the file is not written and a "finish" event will be fired?

Answer (score 45):

Well, usually it is good to avoid asynchronous file operations. Here is the short (i.e. no error handling) sync example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync(targetFile, fs.readFileSync(sourceFile));
```

Comment: To say that in general is extremely false, particularly since it leads to people re-slurping files for every request made to their server. This can get expensive.

Comment: using the `*Sync` methods are totally against nodejs' philosphy! I also think they are slowly being deprecated. The whole idea of nodejs is that it's single threaded and event-driven.

Comment: @gillyb The only reason I can think of for using them is for simplicity - if you are writing a quick script that you will only use once, you probably aren't going to be all that bothered about blocking the process.

Comment: I'm not aware of them being deprecated. Sync methods are almost always a terrible idea on a web server but sometimes ideal in something like node-webkit where it only locks up action in the window while files are copying. Throw up a loading gif and maybe a load bar that updates at certain points and let sync methods block all action until the copying is done. It's not really a best practice thing so much as a when and where they have their place thing.

Comment: Keep in mind that this works ONLY if sourceFile fits into memory (i.e.: don't do this with huge files).

Comment: To give an example for using synchronous copying: I have a npm script that needs a config file. If none exists yet, I copy a default one to the config file location before require'ing the config file. When using the asynchronous copy, the require doesn't see the new config file..

Comment: Sync methods are fine when you are interacting with another sync operation or what you want is to perform sequential operation (ie. you would be emulating sync anyway). If the operations are sequential just avoid the callback hell (and/or promise soup) and use the sync method.

In general they should be used with caution on servers but are fine for most cases that involve CLI scripts.

Comment: for tools and build operations it just bloats your code to use syncronous stuff. good solution.

Comment: i downvoted this but later ended up using it as best answer - apologies - it wont let me upvote - if u edit it it will let me!

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's helpful to EVER say something like 'a synchronous op is preferable in nodejs'. That's contrary to what is pretty much rule #1 in node: make everything async where possible. Emphasis is on "where possible". If your file copy is required for subsequent logic then yes, it should be sync (and even then, maybe not). But if you're spitting out a log that will be used later or something unrelated to the current application then it's 100% preferable. For those beginners out there, just understand, contrary to this answer, IT IS USUALLY BAD TO AVOID ASYNC OPS IN NODE.

Comment: @danielkullmann OFC it won't see the config file if you write the require just after the asynchronous method, that is how wrong you may have design your process in the first place, the whole asynchronous philosophy is "do something when I finish", that means you have to call your require when the Promise resolves...

Comment: @gillyb the `*Sync` being deprecated ?... hum... that's why `fs.exists()` is deprecated and `fs.existsSync()` is not. lol.

Comment: Asynchronous operations are appropriate on web servers, where node.js can handle other http requests while the file is being copied. Using synchronous operations is easier, though, and they are appropriate in command-line scripts in which your script is the only one running in the process.

Comment: asynchronous operations drastically complicate your code. If you follow the "synchronous is bad on a web server" dogma and it takes you ten times longer to write worse code and speed isn't even an issue then you've just written unmaintainable code for no reason. Maybe do some speed tests and see if the extra 20ms it buys you really matter. Also, are you caching the files anyways? I am selling async framework pipe grease for 1BTC/Kb if anyone needs some.

Comment: How is it better than `fs.copyFileSync`?

Answer (score 19):

If you don't care about it being async, and aren't copying gigabyte-sized files, and would rather not add another dependency just for a single function:

```
function copySync(src, dest) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync(src);
  fs.writeFileSync(dest, data);
}
```

Comment: @RobGleeson, and requires as much memory as the file content... I am amazed by the count of upvotes there.

Comment: I've added a "and aren't copying gigabyte-sized files" caveat.

Comment: The `fs.existsSync` call should be omitted. The file could disappear in the time between the `fs.existsSync` call and the `fs.readFileSync` call, which means the `fs.existsSync` call doesn't protect us from anything.

Comment: Additionally, returning `false` if `fs.existsSync` fails is likely poor ergonomics because few consumers of `copySync` will think to manually inspect the return value every time it's called, any more than we do for `fs.writeFileSync` *et al.*. Throwing an exception is actually preferable.

Comment: The OP does not specifically mention that their files are UTF-8 text, so I'm removing the `'utf-8'` encoding from the snippet too, which means this will now work on any file. `data` is now a `Buffer`, not a `String`.

Answer (score 18):

Mike Schilling's solution with error handling with a shortcut for the error event handler.

```
function copyFile(source, target, cb) {
  var cbCalled = false;

  var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
  rd.on("error", done);

  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
  wr.on("error", done);
  wr.on("close", function(ex) {
    done();
  });
  rd.pipe(wr);

  function done(err) {
    if (!cbCalled) {
      cb(err);
      cbCalled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You may want to use async/await, since `node v10.0.0` it's possible with the built-in `fs Promises API`.

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const copyFile = async (src, dest) => {
  await fs.promises.copyFile(src, dest)
}
```

Note:

> As of `node v11.14.0, v10.17.0` the API is no longer experimental.

More information:

[Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

[Promises copyFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_copyfile_src_dest_mode)

Answer (score 7):

```
   const fs = require("fs");
   fs.copyFileSync("filepath1", "filepath2"); //fs.copyFileSync("file1.txt", "file2.txt");
```

This is what I personally use to copy a file and replace another file using Node.js :)

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is about how to efficiently copy files in an IO-heavy application.

Comment: @JaredSmith True, but my google search lead me here and this is what I wanted.

Comment: I wonder why copyFileSync in an async function wouldn't perform well. I would think it would be optimized to match copyFile or stream copying.

Answer (score 2):

For fast copies you should use the `fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE` flag. It allows (for filesystems that support this) to not actually copy the content of the file. Just a new file entry is created, but it points to a [Copy-on-Write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write#In_computer_storage) "clone" of the source file.

To do nothing/less is the fastest way of doing something ;)

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback

```js
let fs = require("fs");

fs.copyFile(
  "source.txt",
  "destination.txt",
  fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE,
  (err) => {
    if (err) {
      // TODO: handle error
      console.log("error");
    }
    console.log("success");
  }
);
```

Using promises instead:

```js
let fs = require("fs");
let util = require("util");
let copyFile = util.promisify(fs.copyFile);


copyFile(
  "source.txt",
  "destination.txt",
  fs.constants.COPYFILE_FICLONE
)
  .catch(() => console.log("error"))
  .then(() => console.log("success"));
```

Comment: `fs.promises.copyFile`

Comment: Re *"To do nothing/less is the fastest way of doing something"*: Yes, indeed. That is the first rule of optimisation - ***eliminate unnecessary operations***. That is in contrast to make the existing ones go faster, e.g. by fiddling with compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Node.js's built-in copy function**

It provides both async and sync version:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// File "destination.txt" will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('source.txt', 'destination.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) 
      throw err;
  console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');
});
```

*[fs.copyFileSync(src, dest[, mode])](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfilesync_src_dest_mode)*

Comment: Not upvoting because this answer is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `fs-extra` module very easily:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');

let srcDir = 'path/to/file';
let destDir = 'pat/to/destination/directory';

fse.moveSync(srcDir, destDir, function (err) {

    // To move a file permanently from a directory
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log("success!");
    }
});
```

***Or***

```
fse.copySync(srcDir, destDir, function (err) {

     // To copy a file from a directory
     if (err) {
         console.error(err);
     } else {
         console.log("success!");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little utility to test the different methods:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-speed-test

run it with

```
npx copy-speed-test --source someFile.zip --destination someNonExistentFolder
```

It does a native copy using child_process.exec(), a copy file using fs.copyFile and it uses createReadStream with a variety of different buffer sizes (you can change buffer sizes by passing them on the command line. run npx copy-speed-test -h for more info).

Answer (score -1):

[Mike's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14387791/65387), but with promises:

```
const FileSystem = require('fs');

exports.copyFile = function copyFile(source, target) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const rd = FileSystem.createReadStream(source);
        rd.on('error', err => reject(err));
        const wr = FileSystem.createWriteStream(target);
        wr.on('error', err => reject(err));
        wr.on('close', () => resolve());
        rd.pipe(wr);
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Improvement of one other answer.

Features:

- If the dst folders do not exist, it will automatically create it. The other answer will only throw errors.
- It returns a `promise`, which makes it easier to use in a larger project.
- It allows you to copy *multiple* files, and the promise will be done when all of them are copied.

Usage:

```
var onePromise = copyFilePromise("src.txt", "dst.txt");
var anotherPromise = copyMultiFilePromise(new Array(new Array("src1.txt", "dst1.txt"), new Array("src2.txt", "dst2.txt")));
```

Code:

```
function copyFile(source, target, cb) {
    console.log("CopyFile", source, target);

    var ensureDirectoryExistence = function (filePath) {
        var dirname = path.dirname(filePath);
        if (fs.existsSync(dirname)) {
            return true;
        }
        ensureDirectoryExistence(dirname);
        fs.mkdirSync(dirname);
    }
    ensureDirectoryExistence(target);

    var cbCalled = false;
    var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
    rd.on("error", function (err) {
        done(err);
    });
    var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
    wr.on("error", function (err) {
        done(err);
    });
    wr.on("close", function (ex) {
        done();
    });
    rd.pipe(wr);
    function done(err) {
        if (!cbCalled) {
            cb(err);
            cbCalled = true;
        }
    }
}

function copyFilePromise(source, target) {
    return new Promise(function (accept, reject) {
        copyFile(source, target, function (data) {
            if (data === undefined) {
                accept();
            } else {
                reject(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

function copyMultiFilePromise(srcTgtPairArr) {
    var copyFilePromiseArr = new Array();
    srcTgtPairArr.forEach(function (srcTgtPair) {
        copyFilePromiseArr.push(copyFilePromise(srcTgtPair[0], srcTgtPair[1]));
    });
    return Promise.all(copyFilePromiseArr);
}
```

Comment: What other answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Mike Schilling's.