# Node.js copy /b files

Tags: node.js

I am not sure what the Windows command "copy /b ..." exactly does, so my questions are: Can this be done with Node.js? How?

Could you please give me an example or at least point me to the right direction?

For e. g.: "copy /b file1+file2 destinationFile"

Thank you.

Comment: @ppeterka: My question is, "What is my question?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to copy file in node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`copy` is an internal command in Windows. `copy /b file1+file2 destinationFile` creates destinationFile with contents of file1 followed by file2 including extra characters like EOF due to `/b`.

Here is how to do it in node.js :

```
fs = require('fs');

file1=fs.createReadStream('./file1',{ flags: 'r',  encoding: "binary",});
file2=fs.createReadStream('./file2',{ flags: 'r',  encoding: "binary",});

dest=fs.createWriteStream('./destinationFile',{ flags: 'w',  encoding: "binary",});

file1.pipe(dest, { end: false });
file2.pipe(dest, { end: false });
```

Comment: I also thank you for this snippet of code. Very easy to follow.