# npm test watch "unloads" Angular 2nd time around?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, mocha.js

I have an app running in node and I have my tests running in Mocha using Chai for asserts. I'm also using Angular and for the tests, I need to load Angular into the window object and a few other bits which I am doing with a **testHelper.js** and using **jsdom**:

```
/* global window */
const jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

global.document = jsdom().defaultView;
global.window = global.document;

global.navigator = window.navigator = {};
global.Node = window.Node;

global.window.mocha = {};
global.window.beforeEach = beforeEach;
global.window.afterEach = afterEach;

require('angular/angular');
require('angular-mocks');

global.angular = window.angular;
global.inject = global.angular.mock.inject;
global.ngModule = global.angular.mock.module;

require('../client/src/app');
```

I have a **test** script in my **package.json** as:

```
"test": "mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"test/*.js\""
```

When I run `npm run test`, works fine. Test run and pass/fail as expected.

I have then set up a script for **start** (so `npm run start`) which runs my app, runs tests and lints and then watches for file changes. This runs fine for the first pass:

```
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch"
```

(the full scripts section of my package.json is below so you can see these commands)

When I then save a file to trigger the watch, I receive the error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mock' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Git\local-poker-club\tools\testSetup.js:18:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:222:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:219:14)
    at Mocha.run (D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:487:10)
    at loadAndRun (D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:416:22)
    at rerun (D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:444:5)
    at D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha:452:7
    at StatWatcher.<anonymous> (D:\Git\local-poker-club\node_modules\mocha\lib\utils.js:196:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at StatWatcher.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at StatWatcher._handle.onchange (fs.js:1487:10)
```

It's as if Angular loads fine onto the window object and then somehow gets wiped out. When I debug it, on first pass, right before the line `require('angular/angular');` the `window.angular` is correctly `undefined` but after that line is excecuted, it is correctly defined. This doesn't happen the second time around, it is always `undefined`

Here is the full scripts section of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"test/*.js\"",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/esw webpack.config.* client server",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node server/app.js",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocha preserve file state in test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899459/mocha-preserve-file-state-in-test)