# How to know if a file is actually opened or closed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch

Node.js provides natively the package filesystem which allows you to read, write and especially to make a watch on a file.

My problem is that the fs watch does not allow you to know when a file is open or closed

I would like to know if there is another package available to do this operation, could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [flag](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags) `r+` for that.

```
fs.open('filename.doc','r+', function(err,data) {
    // throws an error when the file is opened
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this tool:
https://github.com/ronomon/opened

mentionned here:
[Check if a file is open in another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172728/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-another-process)

Answer (score 0):

some app like **word** create temp file in same directory of orginal word file

you can check it is exist or not

Comment: It's preceded by a `~` I guess