# How to know if file finished downloading?

Tags: javascript, download, electron

I am developing an app for both mac and windows using electron that watches a folder for files that got downloaded there from another app, I want to check if file finishes downloading before moving it somewhere else, I don't know if should I check the file size periodically or is there another way to know if the file did finish downloading using javascript.

Comment: What platform?  I suppose there might be an OS-specific way of determining what locks are on the file.

Comment: I am developing for both mac and windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `fs.watch` and `@ronomon/opened` to solve your task. see: [Check if a file is open in another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31172728/check-if-a-file-is-open-in-another-process)

I wrote a simple script, which worked fine on my windows 10 mashine. I downloaded a few files into the folder and it printed a correct notification, when download ended.

```
const fs = require ('fs');
const path = require ("path")
const opened = require('@ronomon/opened');

const base_path = "."
fs.watch (base_path, {encoding: "ascii", recursive: true}, (eventType, filename)=> {

    var file_path = path.join (base_path, filename);
    opened.files ([file_path], (error, hashtable) => {
        try {
            if (!hashtable[file_path]) {
                console.log ("file is closed and can be further processed", file_path)
            } else {
                console.log ("file is still opend by any other process...", file_path)
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error ("error: ", e);
        }
    })
});
```