# node.js and ncp module - fails to copy single file

Tags: node.js

I am using [Node.js v6.3.1](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/) and [ncp v2.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp)

I can only get ncp to copy the contents of a directory, but not a single file within that directory.

Here is the code copying the contents of a directory recursively that works:

```
var ncp = require("ncp").ncp;
ncp("source/directory/", "destination/directory/", callback);
```

...and here is the same code but with a file as the source:

```
var ncp = require("ncp").ncp;
ncp("source/directory/file.txt", "destination/directory/", callback);
```

From this all I can think is that ncp was specifically designed to copy directories recursively, not single files maybe?

I had thought about using something like fileSystem's [read](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream)/[write](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream) stream functions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295106/532489) but really for consistency I was hoping to stick with ncp.

Update:

I have found another package called [node-fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fs-extra) which does what I want without the need for me to add event handlers to the operations, like I would have to do with the fileSystem read/write solution.

Here is the code that is working:

```
var fsExtra = require("fs-extra");
fsExtra.copy("source/directory/file.txt", "destination/directory/file.txt", callback);
```

Obviously this still is inconsistent, but at least is a little less verbose.

Comment: Looking at their source code, they do appear to be able to copy just one file.  I don't think it matters, but for your awareness you don't have to call '.ncp()' on the module, you could just `require('ncp')` and the resulting object is the same as calling `.ncp()` on it, for... reasons.  Their code is a tad fugly.

Comment: @Paul could you provide an example of the syntax so I know where I'm going wrong with the usage, thanks.

Comment: It's the syntax you were using still.  They literally set:  `module.exports = ncp; ncp.ncp = ncp;`  No idea why.  So it'd still be something like `const ncp = require('ncp');  ncp(src, dest, cb);`

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, I meant could you provide an example of copying a single file using ncp. the above syntax is not working for me. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that it's not working; what I'm saying is that there is no different syntax for a single file.  They use fs.stats under the hood to determine if you're grabbing a single file or directory, then call a different private function for each case.  This is also comments not an answer b/c I don't see a good reason that your code isn't working based on what I'm seeing in their source.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll have a closer look again at the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I have figured out what I was doing wrong.

I was trying to copy a file into a directory, where as I needed to copy and name the file inside a directory.

So here is my original code that does not work:

```
var ncp = require("ncp");
ncp("source/directory/file.txt", "destination/directory/", callback);
```

...and here is the fixed code working, notice the inclusion of a file name in the destination directory:

```
var ncp = require("ncp");
ncp("source/directory/file.txt", "destination/directory/file.txt", callback);
```

So it looks like ncp wont just take the file as is, but needs you to specify the file name at the other end to successfully copy. I guess I was assuming that it would just copy the file with the same name into the destination directory.

Answer (score 1):

I have found another package called [node-fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fs-extra) which does what I want without the need for me to add event handlers to the operations, like I would have to do with the fileSystem read/write solution.

Here is the code that is working:

```
var fsExtra = require("fs-extra");
fsExtra.copy("source/directory/file.txt", "destination/directory/file.txt", callback);
```

Obviously this still is inconsistent, but at least is a little less verbose.