# node.js ncp | fs.readdir | missing files | use of callback

Tags: node.js, fs, readdir

I´ve tried to copy a lot of files in folder by "ncp", but every time I check if the files are copied, not all of them are there. There are always some files are missing.

I´ve tried to use fs.readdir to check that are all files there but fs gives me the same result there are some files are missing

**my ncp code**

```
ncp(path.join(req.body.uploadPath,req.body.packageName,resourceDirectoryName), path.join(req.body.uploadPath,req.body.packageName),  (err) => {
    if (err) {
     //devmode report
     devMode.report('**error** '+err); 
    }
})
```

**my fs code**

```
fs.readdir(path.join(req.body.uploadPath,req.body.packageName,resourceDirectoryName), (err, files)=>{
              console.log('####', files)
})
```

**And this is the fs.readdir result**

[image]

**This is the folder with all files that I want to copy**

[image]

**This is the list of files it didn't copy**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- CLUE 1:

  > Check the order reported on your fs.readdir
- CLUE 2:

  > Now, as it´s alphabetical order, look for the next ocurrence in your list (alphabetically)
- CLUE 3:

  > Check for special characters on it´s name.
- CLUE 4 - TEST A POSSIBLE SOLUTION*

  > As you can see, there is a space on the name of `new dictionary.json". Remove the spaces on this name and try again.
- CLUE 5 - Change your call, and add `StopOnError`

> Add an StopOnError option to show if it stops there and why

```
ncp ( 
  path.join(req.body.uploadPath, req.body.packageName,   resourceDirectoryName),
  path.join(req.body.uploadPath,req.body.packageName), 
  {stopOnErr: true},
  (err) => {
        if (err) 
        {
          return console.error(err);
        }
      console.log("ok");
   }
)
```

**SOLUTION**

> After dealing with this for a little of time, the problem was located:
>   The user was executing the fs.readdir right after the execution of
>   NCP. **As NCP is asyncronous, fs.readdir was not reading the whole bunch
>   of copied files**, as they were still not copied.
>
> Then, just a delay before fs.readdir was the solution to see all of them. Not a Spaces or special characters thing.

**FINALLY, A REAL SOLUTION**

> As async programming has a first-day-of-school where everybody learns
>   how to deal with callbacks, there is an example to deal with
>   callbacks, and solve the question.

```
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;
var fs = require('fs');


ncp.limit = 16;
var source="dir1"
var destination="dir2"
console.log('Starting');
console.log(new Date().toISOString());

ncp(source, destination, mycallback );

function mycallback(err)
{
 //here we are inside a callback declared in an outer function
 if (err) {
   return console.log(err);
 }
 console.log('done!');
 console.log(new Date().toISOString());
 fs.readdir(destination, function (err, files){
            console.log("Files Copied to Dir2 "+ files.length);
            //here we are inside fs.readdir callback
            copyTwo();
              });
 //as fs.readdir is also async, I cannot execute copyTwo() here, and I must execute inside fs.reddir callback
}


function copyTwo()
{
console.log('Starting CopyTwo');
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
source="dir2"
destination="dir3"
  //This function uses an embedded callback
  ncp(source, destination, function (err)
  {
   // here we are inside the function declared (with-no-name) to use directly asembedded  callback
   if (err) {
     return console.log(err);
   }
   console.log('done!');
   console.log(new Date().toISOString());
   fs.readdir(destination, function (err, files){
              console.log("Files Copied to Dir3 "+ files.length);
                });
  });
}




[admin-sp@localhost pruebaApp]$ ls dir1 | wc -l
7777
[admin-sp@localhost pruebaApp]$ ls dir2 | wc -l
0
[admin-sp@localhost pruebaApp]$ ls dir3 | wc -l
0
[admin-sp@localhost pruebaApp]$ node index.js
Starting
2018-05-01T00:55:50.683Z
done!
2018-05-01T00:55:57.063Z
Files Copied to Dir2 7777
Starting CopyTwo
2018-05-01T00:55:57.069Z
done!
2018-05-01T00:56:03.030Z
Files Copied to Dir3 7777
[admin-sp@localhost pruebaApp]$
```

Comment: I tried this but give me "ok" on console and the same issue is exist some file not copied

Comment: Did you tried deleting the space on the `new dictionary.json` , renaming as `new_dictionary.json` for example?

Comment: no , i didn't because in normal i don't know files's name in folder , i just after that issue i open folder and check files's name

Comment: Here, they also say you need the filename on destination. Maybe this need is related to the space on filename.. ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38639253/3617531

Comment: I don't guess that because there is a file also sw.js it hasn't space and not copied

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/38639253/3617531  in this ask topic he copy one single file he know its name already but i copy whole folder

Comment: Did you checked it? That is an important point. If you Guess you dont need to, you should not ask for help....

Comment: sir did you see this img "https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWGSH.png" this is a list of files npc and fs cant read and copy them , it isn't case of space in name it's something else

Comment: ok, and..... can you guess why are exactly the next ones to “new dictionary.json”????

Comment: i don't know why , but i try it in Linux and fs.reddir catch these files  [ '.DS_Store',
  'appmanifest.json',
  'box2d.asm.js',
  'c2runtime.js',
  'data.js',
  'data.json',
  'game.html',
  'icon.png',
  'icons',
  'images',
  'media',
  'new dictionary.json' ] 
but still the files in the image fs can't read why !! i don't know

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo I Told You:  The files BEFORE the file with the space in the name, are copied. 

The files AFTER the file with the space in the name are NOT COPIED. 
**That shows, at least, a clear relation between the problem you report and this file**. .. If you are still thinking there is no relation...  I don´t understand what you guess is the problem....

Comment: i did what did you say and it's work but still some files not copy !! i don't know why i check all files's name to remove a space or simple but not found , what you guess ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169784/discussion-between-alejandro-teixeira-munoz-and-mahmoud-niypoo).

Comment: thank you very much you inspired me i  figure out where is a problem , it isn't space , i read files before write them at all i delay the read step and yeaah I catch all files

Comment: :) I told you!!! It was so extrange.  Dealing with async code is not as easy as it´s expected to!! :)

Comment: :( i didn't attention about async cause of I used callback from function , so i guess it's done and i ready to handle this callback , how can i avoid that error that association with async

Comment: added an answer about handling the callback!! :) hope it helps!