# File gets copies with 0kb size using nodeJS

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-webkit

I want to copy a file from a folder to another folder present in my PC using node.js. Below is the code. File gets transfered with 0kb. Please suggest how to solve this?

```
function copyFile(source, target) {
     var readerStream = fs.createReadStream(source);
     var writerStream = fs.createWriteStream(target);
     readerStream.pipe(writerStream);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This could be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js  Do you get any errors?

Comment: There is no problem with the function. check your 'target' path.