# Promise All in Node.js with a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that reads a directory and copies and creates a new file within that directory.

```js
function createFiles (countryCode) {
  fs.readdir('./app/data', (err, directories) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      directories.forEach((directory) => {
        fs.readdir(`./app/data/${directory}`, (err, files) => {
          if (err) console.log(err)
          console.log(`Creating ${countryCode}.yml for ${directory}`)
          fs.createReadStream(`./app/data/${directory}/en.yml`).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./app/data/${directory}/${countryCode}.yml`))
        })
      })
    }
  })
}
```

How do I do this using promises or Promise All to resolve when it's complete?

Comment: You would need to wrap the `fs` methods to make them promise returning.  Or use something like: https://github.com/normalize/mz

Comment: Take a look at this example of recursive directory copy: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/blob/master/examples/node-copy-files/index.js

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to wrap each file stream in a promise that resolves when the stream emits the `finish` event:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.createReadStream(`./app/data/${directory}/en.yml`).pipe(
    fs.createWriteStream(`./app/data/${directory}/${countryCode}.yml`)
  ).on('finish', resolve);
});
```

The you need to collect these promises in an array. This is done by using `map()` instead of `forEach()` and returning the promise:

```
var promises = directories.map((directory) => {
  ...
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream( ...
    ...
  });
});
```

Now you have a collection of promises that you can wrap with `Promise.all()` and use with a handler when all the wrapped promises have resolved:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(completeFunction);
```

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Node (8.0.0 and later), there's a new [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function you can use to get a promise. Here's how we might use it:

```
// Of course we'll need to require important modules before doing anything
// else.
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')

// We use the "promisify" function to make calling promisifiedReaddir
// return a promise.
const promisifiedReaddir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)

// (You don't need to name the variable util.promisify promisifiedXYZ -
// you could just do `const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)` - but
// I call it promisifiedReaddir here for clarity.

function createFiles(countryCode) {
  // Since we're using our promisified readdir function, we'll be storing
  // a Promise inside of the readdirPromise variable..
  const readdirPromise = promisifiedReaddir('./app/data')

  // ..then we can make something happen when the promise finishes (i.e.
  // when we get the list of directories) by using .then():
  return readdirPromise.then(directories => {
    // (Note that we only get the parameter `directories` here, with no `err`.
    // That's because promises have their own way of dealing with errors;
    // try looking up on "promise rejection" and "promise error catching".)

    // We can't use a forEach loop here, because forEach doesn't know how to
    // deal with promises. Instead we'll use a Promise.all with an array of
    // promises.

    // Using the .map() method is a great way to turn our list of directories
    // into a list of promises; read up on "array map" if you aren't sure how
    // it works.
    const promises = directory.map(directory => {
      // Since we want an array of promises, we'll need to `return` a promise
      // here. We'll use our promisifiedReaddir function for that; it already
      // returns a promise, conveniently.
      return promisifiedReaddir(`./app/data/${directory}`).then(files => {
        // (For now, let's pretend we have a "copy file" function that returns
        // a promise. We'll actually make that function later!)
        return copyFile(`./app/data/${directory}/en.yml`, `./app/data/${directory}/${countryCode}.yml`)
      })
    })

    // Now that we've got our array of promises, we actually need to turn them
    // into ONE promise, that completes when all of its "children" promises
    // are completed. Luckily there's a function in JavaScript that's made to
    // do just that - Promise.all:
    const allPromise = Promies.all(promises)

    // Now if we do a .then() on allPromise, the function we passed to .then()
    // would only be called when ALL promises are finished. (The function
    // would get an array of all the values in `promises` in order, but since
    // we're just copying files, those values are irrelevant. And again, don't
    // worry about errors!)

    // Since we've made our allPromise which does what we want, we can return
    // it, and we're done:
    return allPromise
  })
}
```

Okay, but, there's probably still a few things that might be puzzling you..

**What about errors?** I kept saying that you don't need to worry about them, but it *is* good to know a little about them. Basically, in promise-terms, when an error happens inside of a `util.promisify`'d function, we say that that promise *rejects*. Rejected promises behave mostly the same way you'd expect errors to; they throw an error message and stop whatever promise they're in. So if one of our `promisifiedReaddir` calls rejects, it'll stop the whole `createFiles` function.

**What about that `copyFile` function?** Well, we have two options:

1. Use somebody else's function. No need to re-invent the wheel! [`quickly-copy-file`](https://github.com/paulmillr/quickly-copy-file#readme) looks to be a good module (plus, it returns a promise, which is useful for us).
2. Program it ourselves.

Programming it ourselves isn't too hard, actually, but it takes a little bit more than simply using `util.promisify`:

```
function copyFile(from, to) {
  // Hmm.. we want to copy a file. We already know how to do that in normal
  // JavaScript - we'd just use a createReadStream and pipe that into a
  // createWriteStream. But we need to return a promise for our code to work
  // like we want it to.

  // This means we'll have to make our own hand-made promise. Thankfully,
  // that's not actually too difficult..

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Yikes! What's THIS code mean?
    // Well, it literally says we're returning a new Promise object, with a
    // function given to it as an argument. This function takes two arguments
    // of its own: "resolve" and "reject". We'll look at them separately
    // (but maybe you can guess what they mean already!).

    // We do still need to create our read and write streams like we always do
    // when copying files:
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(from)
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(to)

    // And we need to pipe the read stream into the write stream (again, as
    // usual):
    readStream.pipe(writeStream)

    // ..But now we need to figure out how to tell the promise when we're done
    // copying the files.

    // Well, we'll start by doing *something* when the pipe operation is
    // finished. That's simple enough; we'll just set up an event listener:
    writeStream.on('close', () => {
      // Remember the "resolve" and "reject" functions we got earlier? Well, we
      // can use them to tell the promise when we're done. So we'll do that here:
      resolve()
    })

    // Okay, but what about errors? What if, for some reason, the pipe fails?
    // That's simple enough to deal with too, if you know how. Remember how we
    // learned a little on rejected promises, earlier? Since we're making
    // our own Promise object, we'll need to create that rejection ourself
    // (if anything goes wrong).

    writeStream.on('error', err => {
      // We'll use the "reject" argument we were given to show that something
      // inside the promise failed. We can specify what that something is by
      // passing the error object (which we get passed to our event listener,
      // as usual).
      reject(err)
    })

    // ..And we'll do the same in case our read stream fails, just in case:
    readStream.on('error', err => {
      reject(err)
    })

    // And now we're done! We've created our own hand-made promise-returning
    // function, which we can use in our `createFiles` function that we wrote
    // earlier.
  })
}
```

..And here's *all* the finished code, so that you can review it yourself:

```
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')

const promisifiedReaddir = util.promisify(fs.readdir)

function createFiles(countryCode) {
  const readdirPromise = promisifiedReaddir('./app/data')

  return readdirPromise.then(directories => {
    const promises = directory.map(directory => {
      return promisifiedReaddir(`./app/data/${directory}`).then(files => {
        return copyFile(`./app/data/${directory}/en.yml`, `./app/data/${directory}/${countryCode}.yml`)
      })
    })

    const allPromise = Promies.all(promises)

    return allPromise
  })
}

function copyFile(from, to) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(from)
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(to)
    readStream.pipe(writeStream)

    writeStream.on('close', () => {
      resolve()
    })

    writeStream.on('error', err => {
      reject(err)
    })

    readStream.on('error', err => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Of course, this implementation isn't *perfect*. You could improve it by looking at other implementations - for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405105/4633828) destroys the read and write streams when an error occurs, which is a bit cleaner than our method (which doesn't do that). The most reliable way would probably to go with [the module](https://github.com/paulmillr/quickly-copy-file) I linked earlier!

---

I *highly* recommend you watch [funfunfunction's video on promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2d7s3spWAzo). It explains how promises work in general, how to use `Promise.all`, and more; and he's almost certainly better at explaining this whole concept than I am!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function that returns a promise:

```
function processDirectory(directory) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(`./app/data/${directory}`, (err, files) => {
      if (err) reject(err);

      console.log(`Creating ${countryCode}.yml for ${directory}`);

      fs.createReadStream(`./app/data/${directory}/en.yml`)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./app/data/${directory}/${countryCode}.yml`))
        .on('finish', resolve);
    });
  });
}
```

Then use Promise.all:

```
Promise.all(directories.map(processDirectory))
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

Comment: It was a typo, I would write (directory) => processDirectory(directory), but yeah, it can be simplified in that way (as edited now). Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't resolve when writing the new file has completed, it resolves right as the stream starts to write to the new file

Comment: Is not createWriteStream synchronous?

Comment: Oh, you need the on('finish, ...), you are right. I will edit my answer. Thanks!