# Using Javascript as hook for cordova project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, cordova, hook

I'm having a cordova project running in Visual Studio. Before the build process I want to use the hook functionality in order to copy an additional gradle file to the corresponding platforms folder. For copying this file I'm using a simple javascript file. I want to use js because it is independent of the OS.

I use the following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js):

```
  source = "D:\\myProject\\config\\build-extras.gradle";
  target = "D:\\myProject\\platforms\\android\\build-extras.gradle";

  var fs = require('fs');
  var cbCalled = false;

  var rd = fs.createReadStream(source);
  rd.on("error", function(err) {
    done(err);
  });

  var wr = fs.createWriteStream(target);
  wr.on("error", function(err) {
    done(err);
  });

  wr.on("close", function(ex) {
    done();
  });
  rd.pipe(wr);

  function done(err) {
    if (!cbCalled) {
        console.log("Something wrong with copy of build-extras.gradle: " + err);
      cbCalled = true;
    }
  }
```

When I run this code in a console with node, then the script is copying the file as expected.
However, when I include the same script in my config.xml file of cordova the script is doing something different: It creates a file with the defined name but the file is always empty. 
Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: If the gradle file has settings related to a certain plugin, why not include it in the plugin itself? When installing the plugin then, its settings will be auto-merged into the final gradle file.