# Pipe doesn't write to new writeStream

Tags: node.js

I try to copy a file with pipe but after code is run there is only an empty file. In the console is no error.

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( newLocation); // album1/fff28042018.jpg
writeStream.on('error', function(e){console.log(e)});

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(oldLocation); // imagesource/fff.jpg
readStream.on('error', function(e){console.log(e)});

readStream.pipe(writeStream);
writeStream.close();
readStream.close();
```

I expect that the image from imagesource/fff.jpg to the new file album1/fff28042018.jpg is copied. But in the end i have a new empty file album1/fff28042018.jpg

before the question comes up "Yes the source file exists".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to copy file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are closing the streams before the data transferring finishes. Usually, when the readable finishes piping, it emits `end` on the writable stream and the stream get closed automatically.

Here is the shortest as cited in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js) answer.

```
fs.createReadStream('test.log').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('newLog.log'));
```

Comment: tried it doesn't work :-( . Can there be a permission error that doesn't result in an error in the log?

Comment: Update: on windows it works fine on arch linux not.

Comment: So, this means the problem is in your os - not the code.