# Can't read file after writing it with fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, fs, multiparty

I want to read an image ,write it in a folder and read it again to get it's base64 
I get the following error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'C:\Workspace\Project\upload_storage\image.jpg'
    at Object.accessSync (fs.js:192:3)

My code:

```
const FS = require("fs");
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var path = require('path');
function readAndWriteFile(file , newPath){
  FS.readFileSync(file.path, (err, data)=>{
      FS.writeFileSync(newPath, data, (err)=>{                                                                                                                
          });
  });
}
function base64Encode(path,filemime) {
    FS.readFileSync(path, {encoding: 'base64'}, (err, data)=>{
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      return `data:${filemime};base64,${data}`;
    });
}
```

...

```
          var form = new multiparty.Form()
          //retrieve files using multiparty form
          form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            var document;
            const documents = files.file; 

            for(i=0; i<documents.length; i++){
              document=documents[i];
              const contentType = String(document.headers["content-type"]);
              filePath = path.join(process.cwd(),'/upload_storage/',document.originalFilename);
              readAndWriteFile(document,filePath);
              // // convert image to base64 encoded string
              const base64str = base64Encode(filePath, contentType);
              console.log(base64str);
            }
         }
```

if I comment the base64Encode function call the files get created. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you are using `readFileSync` with the callback, you are instantly returning the function - which continues, regardless of if the call to `writeFileSync` has finished or not. It appears you have a classic case of a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use callbacks with `_fileSync`. But it looks like you want [`copyFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfilesync_src_dest_flags) followed by [`unlinkSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path) anyway:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readAndWriteFile(file , newPath){
  fs.copyFileSync(file.path, newPath);
  fs.unlinkSync(file.path)
}
```

Did you try reading the documentation for [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)?

More reading and examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-file-in-node-js),