# How do I put specific file from external libraries to a more specific folder in my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using NPM as package manager.

These are the dependencies of my project:

```
"dependencies": {
    "litepicker": "2.0.11",
    "moment": "2.29.1"
}
```

I wanted to get litepicker.js and moment.js to my **src/** folder automatically.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: can you share the reason why you want to put it in the project src?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to copy a file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293857/fastest-way-to-copy-a-file-in-node-js)

Comment: You can install it and move it from `node_modules/` to your `src/`

Comment: Should I just use bash script and will run it using npm run build?